# Where the file get transferred while using LocalStorageHelper service for google cloud storage?

Tags: spring, testing, google-cloud-storage

I'm using [LocalStorageHelper](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/main/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-storage) to transfer files to the GCS bucket only for testing purposes in Spring.

```
Storage storage = LocalStorageHelper.getOptions().getService();
```

I'm curious about where these files go after the transfer gets completed. Do I have to clean these files after transferring successfully or it will be cleared automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalStorageHelper` is for in-memory testing. So the objects are stored in the memory of the process you are running. When it exits, there is no more cleanup to do.